# How to filter Spark dataframe if one column is a member of another column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with two columns(one string and one array of string):

```
root
 |-- user: string (nullable = true)
 |-- users: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

How can I filter the dataframe so that the result dataframe only contains rows that `user` is in `users`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, It's possible and not so hard. To achieve this you may use a `UDF`.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df = sc.parallelize(Array(
  ("1", Array("1", "2", "3")),
  ("2", Array("1", "2", "2", "3")),
  ("3", Array("1", "2"))
)).toDF("user", "users")

val inArray = udf((id: String, array: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => array.contains(id), BooleanType)

df.where(inArray($"user", $"users")).show()
```

The output is:

```
+----+------------+
|user|       users|
+----+------------+
|   1|   [1, 2, 3]|
|   2|[1, 2, 2, 3]|
+----+------------+
```

Answer (score 12):

Quick and simple:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr

df.where(expr("array_contains(users, user)")
```

Comment: Thanks. Both this and the accepted one work but I can only accept one as answer.